# Android Nougat wpa_supplicant.conf id_str

Tags: android, android-7.1-nougat, wpa-supplicant

I have upgraded my Nexus 5 to Nougat (7.1.2) and had to wipe it.
I tried to restore my WLAN networks by copying the old wpa_supplicant.conf, which crashed the whole wlan module. By comparing the old to the fresh file I noticed that on the new one the networks contain a new field `id_str`:

Old:

```
network={
    ssid="WLAN2"
    key_mgmt=NONE
    priority=1
}
```

New:

```
network={
    ssid="WLAN2"
    key_mgmt=NONE
    priority=1
    id_str="%7B%22creatorUid%22%3A%221000%22%2C%22configKey%22%3A%22%5C%22WLAN2%5C%22NONE%22%7D"
}
```

Is there any way to generate the id_str, such that dont have to reconfigure all the networks?